# can I connect bespin to github

Tags: github, bespin

I was checking bespin documentation and I found this
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Bespin/DesignDocs/VCSIntegration
Here it says bespin can connect mercurial, svn and git. But I could not find those commands in bespin (I am using it from https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/). I am spesifically trying to find a way to connect bespin to github, so I can have free online code editing solution. Did anybody else tried that? or is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am just quoting from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/bespin/browse_thread/thread/f6355d86fbc4a26d).

> Actually, Bespin already handles
>   that...  "vcs getkey" will generate a
>   keypair for you and give you your
>   public key to  install on
>   GitHub/bitbucket/wherever. It's mostly
>   a matter of being able to  tell git
>   where to find the private key. hg
>   actually has a command line  option
>   that lets you specify the ssh command
>   to run. I believe we'll need to  set
>   environment variables with git and
>   svn.

**Edit:** Also, [a plugin](http://bespinplugins.mozillalabs.com/plugins/20) you may find handy.

Comment: I found some documents that uses vcs commands
https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/docs/userguide/vcs.html
this documents explains it. The problem is there is no such command in public bespin site https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/ it does not know what vcs is. actually there is no command about any version control system. (Maybe they are developed as plugins?) actually I could not find how to turn on "vcs" command.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://bespinplugins.mozillalabs.com/plugins/20) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I found a bespin plugin
http://bespinplugins.mozillalabs.com/plugins/20
unfortunaltely it only fetches gists (gist.github.com) not whole git project.